# Use Laravel without a database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was wondering if the use of a database is necessary on Laravel or I can build an app without database.

I have researched throughout but there is no clear indication of these nor on the Laravel documentation website or other places, it is just vague.

Thanks

Comment: You *can* use Laravel without a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can use Laravel without a database. You can read and save data using remote RESTful API, files etc or you can do not use any data layer at all. Laravel will work just fine.

Also, you can use pretty cool [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) library which allows you to save all info to a single file. [Laravel supports it out of box](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#introduction).

Comment: Thanks, but how do you tell it not to look for a database? If I use the connection = null I get errors :(